# Is there a web browser for Linux that implements the Trident engine (Internet Explorer)?

Tags: windows, browser

Internet Explorer uses the Trident engine for rendering.  I have an app that was made for IE only.  It is a big application I inherited, and it is JavaScript heavy.  It's and older app, and it will not work correctly on newer browsers, even IE, later versions has quirks but it works.  The app is not straight text, so I can't get rid of all the images or anything like that.

I do not have the luxury of installing Linux and then using a VM like VirtualBox to run Windows.  It must be native to Linux (or Linux can run the Windows program, maybe via Wine).

It will not work on Windows non-IE browsers either, but that is another matter.  It is not a trivial matter to change the code.

Is there any browser I can use to emulate IE or that has the Trident engine?

Comment: That is M$ for you .... incompatible interoperability..... I suspect you are out of luck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a list of web browsers that use Trident shell as listed in the wiki page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#Trident_shells).

Apparently, `Tencent` has support for Linux and it [uses](http://www.tencent.com/en-us/ps/imservice.shtml) trident shell.

> Tencent QQ provides total solution for Internet-based instant
>   messaging (IM) platform. It supports comprehensive basic online
>   communication functions, including text messaging, video and voice
>   chat as well as online (offline) file transmission. It also supports
>   cross platform communication between PC and wireless terminals. The
>   new QQ2009 edition is fully compatible with Windows XP, Vista, Linux,
>   Mac and other systems. Meanwhile, the third-generation QQ with
>   "Hummer" as its core has strengthened the integration of various
>   Internet services to build a complete, mature and diversified online
>   life platform for users.

Also [Realplayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RealPlayer) seems to be supported in Linux which has the trident shell.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but this browser no longer supports Linux, at least I wasn't able to find any reference to Linux anywhere and the download page doesn't list Linux either